# Is it possible to convert a JSF web application into a product?

Tags: jsf, architecture, ejb, software-design

We have a web application which is built with the following Java EE technologies:
JSF, Primefaces, EJB.
The application is customized to our client.
We are now considering converting the Application into a product.
What criteria we could use to evaluate the applicability of our plan?

Comment: How is commercializing an application related to EJB's, JSF, architecture and software-design. Technically: Yes you can!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is more of a business case thing than a technical thing.